# A monotone class in $\mathbb{R}$ which is closed under complement but is not a sigma-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Like the title says I'm looking for an example of a monotone class $ \mathcal{M}\subseteq\mathcal{P}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ such that $\mathbb{R}\in\mathcal{M}$ and $ \mathcal{M}$ is closed under complement but is not sigma-algebra.

I'm guessing the idea is to find such a family of sets that isn't closed under finite intersection but I haven't come up with anything thus far.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try it with intervals. (Not *all* intervals, just *some* intervals.)

Comment: I would appreciate a slightly thicker hint about which intervals I should be looking at :)

Comment: The kind of intervals whose complements are also intervals?

Answer (score 4):

Following the hint by Harald Hanche-Olsen: take the collection of all unbounded intervals of $\mathbb R$. This includes $\mathbb R$, so we should throw in the empty set too, to keep the class closed under complements. The monotone   class is not hard to verify. And  finite intersections can create bounded intervals, not in the class.