# Checking an example of a monotone class.

Tags: monotone-class-theorem

Give an example of a monotone class $\mathcal{G}$ on $\mathbb{R}$ that satisfies:
(a) \mathbb{R} belongs to $\mathcal{G},$ and
(b)if $A \in \mathcal{G} $ then its complement $A^c$ is in  $\mathcal{G},$ but it is not a $\sigma-$algebra.

**Here is my trial:**

consider the following set $\{(-\infty, a), (-\infty, a], \emptyset, [a, \infty), (a, \infty)\}$, is this a correct example?if so, where is the increasing and decreasing sequences in $\mathcal{G},$? if not, could anyone provide me with an example please?

**Monotone Class Definition:**

We say that $\mathcal{G}$ is a monotone class if whenever $\{A_{k}\}$ is an increasing and $\{B_{k}\}$ is a decreasing sequence in $\mathcal{G},$ then $\cup A_{k}$ and $\cap B_{k}$ are in $\mathcal{G},$ as well.

Note that I found this question here  [A monotone class in $\mathbb{R}$ which is closed under complement but is not a sigma-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531460/a-monotone-class-in-mathbbr-which-is-closed-under-complement-but-is-not-a-s?rq=1) but it does not fully answer my questions.

Comment: Formatting tip:  type `\{` to get $\{$

Comment: You can exploit the absence of minimality in your question. An example would be to find a non-minimal monotone class generated by $\mathbb{R}$ but contains the Borel sigma algebra.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner thank you :)

Comment: @FrankSwanton could you please in more details as I can not understand you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is correct except that you forgot to include $\mathbb R$. The only way you get a decreasing sequence in this class  is by considering $(-\infty, a_n)$ with $(a_n)$ decreasing, $(-\infty, a_n]$ with $(a_n)$ decreasing or $(a_n,\infty) $ with $(a_n)$ increasing,  or $[ a_n, \infty)$ with $(a_n)$ increasing. Similarly we  can write down increasing sequences.

It is not a sigma algebra because $\{0\}=(-\infty,0]\cap [0,\infty)$ does not belong to it.

Comment: and it is not sigma algebra because (a_{n}) is not in it?

Comment: I have edited the answer to make it complete.

Comment: Is the example given by the OP contains $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Can we proof that $\{0\}$ does not belong to your monotone class? if so, how?

Comment: @Emptymind Every non-empty set in  the family is an infinite set.

Comment: for the example of the OP, can not $(-\infty, a) \cup [a,\infty)$ give us $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: So the correct example is the following set $\{(-\infty, a_{n}), (-\infty, a_{n}], \emptyset, [a_{n}, \infty), (a_{n}, \infty), \mathbb{R}\}$ ... correct?

Comment: What is the meaning of this statement "Similarly we  can write down increasing sequences." in your answer as you already included increasing sequences. Could you elaborate please?